# Loop through and echo all the values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, echo

I have an array, `print_r($badges);` shows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => foobar [2] => foobar2 [4] => foobar3 ) )
```

I want to loop through and print all the values:

```
$arrlength = count($badges);

for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
  echo $badges[$x];
  echo "<br/>";
  }
```

But it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You ask *"What am I doing wrong?"* which so far is not answered: What you really do wrong is that you don't have enabled error reporting to the highest level looking for actual warnings and notices while you develop. You can highly benefit from these. See the following reference question we have on this website: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456).

Comment: @hakre...not having error reporting enabled isn't "wrong". Not best practice, sure, but it has nothing to do with why the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have nested arrays. As a result, you need to target the first item of the parent array (at index `[0]`), and then loop through the values in the child array:

```
foreach ( $badges[0] as $badge ) {
    echo $badge . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: lol, we had exactly the same approach at exactly the same time. :-)

Comment: Ha, I nicked you by 8 seconds. ;-)

Comment: Indeed. Congratulations!

Comment: Cheers guys! Works fine. Which answer should I accept? :)

Comment: Both! If only...I answered slightly ahead; but we're both right.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `$badges` actually holds *an array inside an array*.

Here is the the working and simplified code:

```
foreach ($badges[0] as $badge) {
  echo $badge;
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested array--that is why your `print_r` shows a `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>`. Additionally, you only have even-numbered keys in your array, so using `for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)` is not going to be an optimal solution. You'd be better off with `foreach`, which iterates through each array element. Access the inner array using `$badges[0]`, and then iterate through it:

```
foreach ($badges[0] as $k => $v) {
    echo "key: $k, value: $v" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
key: 0, value: foobar
key: 2, value: foobar2
key: 4, value: foobar3
```